# Instalação compartilhada Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, instalador

Preciso realizar a instalação do Android Studio de forma compartilhada na mesma maquina e criar um repositório local para as atualizações, é possível?
Já revirei a web e não achei nada, por enquanto.
Agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode instalar o Android Studio para todos os usuários. Quanto ao repositório local, já que vai ser usado por outro usuário na mesma maquina, acredito que pode usar a pasta pública 'C:\Users\Public\Documents'.

Dê uma olhada aqui também: [Link](https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-utilizar-usuarios-distintos-no-mesmo-computador-local-para-colaborar-no-git-26002)

Comment: Oi Marcos, agradeço mas pelo que entendi o link se refere a trabalhar no mesmo projeto com usuários diferentes, via GIT, minha busca é para instalar o Android Studio uma única vez e torná-lo acessível para outros usuários da mesma maquina.